# Y axis value not showing even though same exact function worked with other data in R

Tags: r, axis

My plot showed the both axis with their ticks for the following function

```
Hip <- c(31400, 22200, 13700, 7110)
g_range <- range(7000, Hip)
plot(Hip, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE) +
  axis(1, at=1:4, lab=c("100%","80%","60%","40%"))
axis(2, las=1, at=6000*0:g_range[2])
box()
```

but won't do the same for this function

```
tub <- c(.01, .009, .007)
g_range <- range(.006, tub)
plot(tub, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE) +
  axis(1, at=1:3, lab=c("Iso", "Hyper", "Hypo"))
axis(2, las=1, at= .001*0:g_range[2])
box()
```

I'm pretty sure it's because the values are too small, but I tried looking online and couldn't find anything? I also tried par() even though i think that's only for ggplot, and messing around with "at=" but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `0:something` makes sequence of integer and `g_range[2]` is too small. It means, `0:g_range[2]` is only `0`.

This problem can be solved easily multiplying `1000` to `g_range[2]`.

```
tub <- c(.01, .009, .007)
g_range <- range(.006, tub) 
plot(tub, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE) +
  axis(1, at=1:3, lab=c("Iso", "Hyper", "Hypo"))
axis(2, las=1, at= .001*0:(g_range[2]* 1000))
box()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should remove the ` + ` since it's very uncommon to base plots.